# Set icons source from GeoJSON properties in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers

I'm trying to build a map with OpenLayers, from a GeoJSON file where I have a property iconUrl for each point. I want that my style refers to that property, and I can't manage to do it. I did it with Leaflet, you can see the goal here: https://idrissad.github.io/lyon_map/

Here is my OL code:

```
function styleFunction(feature) {
  if (feature.get('iconUrl')) {
    var iconUrl = feature.get('iconUrl');
    console.log(iconUrl);
  }
  var defaultStyle = new ol.style.Style({
   fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: "green"
  }),
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
   color: "green",
   width: 1.2
  }),
  image: new ol.style.Icon({
   scale: 0.1,
   src: iconUrl
  })
 })return [defaultStyle]
}
```

And:

```
const data = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
   url:'data.geojson',
   format: new ol.format.GeoJSON
  }),
  style: styleFunction,
  visible: true
})
```

The error I get is "Assertion failed:6 => A defined and non-empty src or image must be provided."
I tried several options, without success.
My console.log shows me that the feature.get() works fine, I have my urls in the var iconUrl.
Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you also have fill and stroke is your style is it also being used for polygons?  If other features don't have an `iconUrl` that will cause the error.  Try modifying the style function so the image part is only set if there is an `iconUrl`

```
function styleFunction(feature) {
  var iconUrl = feature.get('iconUrl');
  var defaultStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: "green"
  }),
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
   color: "green",
   width: 1.2
  }),
  image: iconUrl ? new ol.style.Icon({
   scale: 0.1,
   src: iconUrl
  }) : undefined
 });
 return [defaultStyle];
}
```

Comment: Yes that was the problem, thanks!
A friend helped me solve it minutes after I posted here, with another function and a if, but your solution is way simpler!
I thought that image was only for points, so that OL wouldn't try to apply it to linestring and polygons features.